# using export and perl -c in perl scripting

Tags: perl, environment-variables

Since export cannot be used with a Perl script I've used the environment variable.

This code doesn't return any error but the command `perl -c` to check the syntax of the .pm file does not print the output.

```
myscript.pl

$ENV{'PATH'}='C:/Users/abc/Desktop/mno/wwwww/scripts/lib/perl/';

system("perl -c ContentModifySeasonPassOverlayRecord.pm");
```

Comment: What is the aim of you script

Comment: If you just want to do `perl -c` on a .pm file you can do that. It's only a syntax check. Do it from the `bin` directory, e.g. `scripts $ perl -c lib/perl/ContentModifySeasonPassOverlayRecord.pm`. That will give you a syntaxcheck.

Comment: i want to run the script outside bin. so i should specify the path for the framework in the script.

Comment: **export PERL5LIB=/home/user/Desktop/QWARTS-0.6/autoinfra/lib/perl/;  do perl -c filename.pm**  This works absolutely in command line.. i want to include this in myscript.pl,and if i do tat export is giving me error, so i used env variable PATH. stil no ouput is printed. so how can i make this into a script so i can test many files at a time?

Comment: I still don't get what you want.

Comment: "export is giving me error" - tell us more about that.  also, what output do you want printed?

Comment: *Since export cannot be used with perl script i've used the environmental variable*  -  `export` is a shell command that turns a local variable into an environment variable.  Every language has a different syntax for setting environment variables.  You imply that you are not using an environment variable in your shell, but you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me make another guess at what you want to do:

You want to batch syntax-check all your Perl modules, maybe in a cronjob. The script you are using to do that is located somewhere outside your working directory (where your framework sits). The scripts you want to check also sit somewhere else.

What you need to do is run the `perl -c` command from where the lib (framework) is, so that the working directory for the script while running has the lib files. You need to **[change](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chdir.html) the working directory** before doing your `perl -c` call, and you need to **include the full path to your scripts** in the call.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
# Change current working directory to where the framework is
chdir('/home/user/Desktop/QWARTS-0.6/autoinfra/lib/perl/');

# Run the perl -c command for each of your scripts you want to check
foreach my $script (qw(ContentModifySeasonPassOverlayRecord.pm otherfiles.pm)) {
  system("perl -c /path/to/your/scripts/$script");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
system("perl -c /root/.cpan/build/DateTime-TimeZone-1.31-oqQt_7/lib/DateTime/TimeZone/America/Noronha.pm");
```

I don't see how it doesn't work?

```
# ./errr.pl 
/root/.cpan/build/DateTime-TimeZone-1.31-oqQt_7/lib/DateTime/TimeZone/America/Noronha.pm syntax OK
```

Comment: **hi.. wt i am trying to do is exporting the framework.. i tried it using export but it dint work so i used the env variable PATH. its not showing any errors but perl -c filename.pm doesnt print the output. **

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing a wrong way to execute a perl script with in perl script 
here is the right way of executing a perl script with in perl script

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::System::Simple qw(system capture);

 # Run a command, wait until it finishes, and make sure it works.
 # Output from this program goes directly to STDOUT, and it can take input
 # from your STDIN if required.
 system($^X, "yourscript.pl", @ARGS);

 # Run a command, wait until it finishes, and make sure it works.
 # The output of this command is captured into $results.
 my $results = capture($^X, "yourscript.pl", @ARGS);
```

And to check the errors in a module , You can just 'use' the module in your perl script and run the script in an usual way , if it has errors it will throw to stdout

If you want to test large number of perl modules you can build a shell script for that purpose .

```
#!/bin/sh
// List all modules 
MODULES="Data::Dumper Foobar::Test"

for i in $MODULES ; do
if $(perl -M$i -e '1;' >/dev/null 2>&1 ); do
echo "Ok."
else
echo "No." 
fi
done
```

Comment: Can you clarify , the purpose of your work , are you just debugging a perl module or you want to call the script with in a script

Comment: **export PERL5LIB=/home/user/Desktop/QWARTS-0.6/autoinfra/lib/perl/;**  **do perl -c filename.pm**  This works absolutely in command line.. i want to include this in myscript.pl,and if i do tat export is giving me error, so i used env variable PATH. stil no ouput is printed. so how can i make this into a script so i can test many files at a time?

Comment: @ajithmathewz I re edited the post , by adding another solution , you have to use shell or bash to make you life easy in these scenarios

Comment: @ aravind.udayashankara:  am new to perl scripting, so can u tell me the purpose of the this statement..  MODULES="Data::Dumper Foobar::Test"  how it works?

Comment: @ajith: what he has done there is Shell, not Perl. **Please try to tell us exactly what you want to do!**

Comment: Wow It is not perl , it is shell scripting , in shell scripting you have lots of flexibility , to run all types of commands , here Modules is the global variable , and you declare all modules that you are testing , and later loop through this variable . with the perl -c option , sorry I have mispelled with -e this will throw an error if exists

Comment: @simbabque: checking for syntax of .pm files which uses frameworks, and its located in `/home/user/Desktop/QWARTS-0.6/autoinfra/lib/perl/`.  so i need to export it before i do `perl -c  xxx.pm`. how can i make it into a script? using export command or using env variable PATH? can u help me out?

Comment: Looks like you are working in windows machine and you cant run the shell script to achive this , I think  @simbabque has given an answer, I think you have missed chdir in your code thats y it is not working

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara:  how ll i use the framework for this? its in `/home/user/Desktop/QWARTS-0.6/autoinfra/lib/perl/`. can i use export? or how?

Comment: do a chdir to /home/user/Desktop/QWARTS-0.6/autoinfra/lib/perl/ this directory and loop through this , an answer has been given to by @simbabque along with the code above please refer that

Comment: i checked the below code.  `use strict; 
use warnings;
chdir('C:/Users/Desktop/QWARTS/MMM/auto/lib/perl');
system("perl -c C:/Users/313550/Desktop/sample/ContentModifySeasonPassOverlayRecord.pm");
#foreach my $script (qw(AAA.pm BBB.pm CCC.pm)) {
#  system("perl -c Users/Desktop/scripts/$script");
#}`  this code throwed me these errors  syncheck.sh: line 2: use: command not found
syncheck.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
line 3: use: command not found
line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `'C:/Users/313550/Desktop/QWARTS/tivo/autoinfra/lib/perl''
'yncheck.sh: line 5:

Comment: Why dont you read the comments properly , I have told you that shell script can not be executed from windows , and you are still trying the same , Please stop stop trying to use shell script in windows . Why dont you see the answer which has been given by @simbabque there above , any ways I pasted the same code in the gist here copy and try running it [link](https://gist.github.com/3697761)

Comment: @ajithmathewz: This is Perl code. You do not run it as a shell script. Run it with perl I put the shebang there for a reason...